# WordPress - не отображает фото для заголовка сайта

Tags: wordpress

### WordPress - не отображает фото для заголовка сайта.
Так на ПК:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
.
.
.

А так на мобильном:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее выяснил, что все фотографии загружаемые на локальный сайт (всегда все проводят разработку на локальных серверах, а потом просто переносят файловой системой + БД) прописались в БД с адресом локального сервера (впервые такое встречаю!). Т.е. адреса у картинок не относительные, а абсолютные(!) - не ожидал такого подвоха от WordPress.

Сейчас просто переписываю перед деплоем 5000 строк запросов из дампа БД.
Но как в будущем избегать таких нюансов?
Где, что поднастроить или поставить галочку?

Answer (score 0):

> всегда все проводят разработку на локальных серверах, а потом просто
> переносят файловой системой + БД

Далеко не все.
Я категорически уверен, что разрабатывать нужно в той же среде, в которой сайт будет эксплуатироваться. В идеале - на том же сервере.

> не ожидал такого подвоха от WordPress

ВП учить нужно.

> Но как в будущем избегать таких нюансов?

[Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562)